# Is there a Dart equivalent of "hashlib.sha512(out.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()"?

Tags: python-3.x, dart, sha512

I am quite new to Dart and I've trying to build an API in Dart. I am facing a problem with the hashing part, how can i get it to output 128 characters just like the method from  python `hashlib.sha512(out.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest().upper()`

I've tried using crypto and pointycastle
The packages output a hash of length less than 128 unlike the one from the Python one.

So what is the best way I can generate sha512 hashes of length 128 in Dart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [crypto](https://pub.dev/packages/crypto) package for this:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';

void main() {
  final hash = sha512.convert(utf8.encode('Hello World'));
  print(hash); // 2c74fd17edafd80e8447b0d46741ee243b7eb74dd2149a0ab1b9246fb30382f27e853d8585719e0e67cbda0daa8f51671064615d645ae27acb15bfb1447f459b
}
```